# How can I order a matrix in Mathematica by its second column?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Imagine you have:

```
a = {{5, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 7}, {3, -4, 6}}
```

and you want to order it by the second column, to get

```
b = {{3, -4, 6}, {2, 0, 7}, {5, 1, 1}}
```

I have tried with `SortBy[a, Last]` and works for the last column, but I can't get it to work for the second column.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Hmmm.... "top 0.23% this year" (Belisarus) vs "top 0.17% this month" (Niels)

Comment: @Brett I am not _Belisarus_, _Champon_ :D

Comment: @belisarius My apologies!  I'll have to add your name to the spell checker on my system.  I'm quite quite amused by the edit history on your answer...

Comment: @Brett I was not aware of the edit history as I only saw Sjoerd's edit, and considered it an enhancement. Looking at the history is also a vote of confidence :D

Answer (score 22):

This does work:

```
SortBy[a,#[[2]]&]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering in less than a minute!!, you saved my day :-D

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively,

```
a[[Ordering[a[[All, 2]]]]]
```

Answer (score 9):

And here,  for the obligatory timing (I added the basic `Sort` to the methods):

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {1000000, 3}];

Sort[a, #2[[2]] < #1[[2]] &]; // Timing

(* ==> {34.367, Null} *)

SortBy[a, #[[2]] &]; // Timing

(* ==> {0.436, Null} *)

 a[[Ordering[a[[All, 2]]]]]; // Timing

(* ==> {0.234, Null}, Chris wins *)
```

Comment: +1, weird. I expected `SortBy` to win, and I did not expect `Sort` to fair that badly.

Comment: +1 We should include a timing addenda on every question. And thank you for editing my answer :)

Comment: @rcollyer More interesting timings here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659227/whats-the-best-way-to-select-the-maximum-one-from-a-list-of-lists-by-their-last

Comment: @rcollyer the `Sort` result is predictable because it introduces an arbitrary ordering function.

Comment: On my machine the ratio between the SortBy and Ordering solutions is only 1.2

Comment: @szabolcs Yeah, short timings are unreliable. I repeated a number of times and get about 1.4

Comment: @mr.wizard Internally, SortBy must also an ordering function, based on the arbitrary transformation function the user provides. A priori, I  wouldn't have been able to tell which way would have been more efficient. Two orders of magnitude is huge.

Comment: @rcollyer, belisarius, Mr.Wizard A relevant MathGroup discussion: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/9e1086e0fac30bb3. I also discussed this topic here: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node291.html, using a similar example.

Comment: @Leonid, yes, I probably learned that from either Mathgroup or your book.

Comment: @mr.wizard I don't think you disagree with me. "Internal ordering function" (my words) = "default ordering function" (your words), "transformation function" (me) ="decorate" (you).

Comment: @Sjoerd I am sure you saw this many times - it seems to be a  frequently discussed topic. Sorry for not including you explicitly in the list  - I knew you would be notified in any case.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was specifically referring to your first sentence. As to the second part: I agree that you should expect external  functions to be slower than internal functions, but in this case we were discussing 'decorated' internal functions that might be just as slow as a simple external function. At least, I had no expectation what decorating internal functions would do for performance.

Comment: @Leonid This case is different from what you linked to.  In the case of `Union` we specify a "same test" (and lose the advantage of also having an "ordering test").  In the case of `Sort` we *only* have an ordering relation.

Comment: @Mr.wizard I understand that. My point is simply that the timing of the process of decorating **and** using the internal ordering function compared to using an external ordering function not only depends on how much faster the internal ordering function is than external ordering, but also on the speed of decorating (which is an external function). Apparently, it is faster, but would you really have bet your life on it?

Comment: @Sjoerd, I think I finally understand **your** point.  My apologies.  I will delete most of the mess above.

Comment: From the discussion above, some numerical experiments, it seems that the user-supplied function will be called ~`1.35 Log[n]` as many times when using `Sort` than when using `SortBy`.  This gives us a factor of ~19 compared to the actual timing ratio of ~100.  Where that 5x difference comes from, I can imagine lots of reasonable explanations, but none that are easily testable.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard Hmmm, where would history be if Einstein and Bohr had done the same? ;-)

Comment: @Szabolcs Strictly speaking, you are right about the link to Mathgroup  post. However, a part of my explanation in that thread which mentions the general M evaluation overhead holds also for `Sort`. My second link to the book page is for `Sort` specifically.

Comment: @Szabolcs No, *you* are right, I should have been more specific when giving that link.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use this url: http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_matlab_control/KERNEL/node99.htm

Code you can use:

```
a={{300,48,2},{500,23,5},{120,55,7},{40,32,1}};
b=SortBy[a, #[[2]]&]
```

Result:

```
Out[9]= {{500,23,5},{40,32,1},{300,48,2},{120,55,7}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the link. In fact I wanted to order in descending order and this works:  SortBy[a, -#[[2]]&]

Answer (score 4):

If your data were:

```
a = {{5, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 7}, {3, -4, 6}}
```

And you needed a stable sort on the second element, yielding:

```
{{3, -4, 6}, {5, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 7}}
```

It could be very frustrating to try to solve this with `SortBy`, unless you were aware of this:

```
SortBy[a, {#[[2]] &}]
```

The `{}` brackets are important.

Comment: It took me a couple  of hours before I noticed you'd posted this. It then took some time before I saw what your point was, and then it took way too long before I understood your point. Interesting, you should've made that more explicit I guess.

Comment: A bit. My first problem was that at first I didn't notice you slightly changed the original data from the question (to introduce the issue of 'ties'), and then I didn't understand why the brackets solved the problem. How ties are resolved if there aren't any extra tie-breaking functions between the brackets isn't documented AFAI can tell.

Comment: I think the tie-breaking rule in the {} case is simply 'first come, first go'. In the no-{} case it is sorting canonically. Try both sorts on `a = {{5, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 7}, {3, -4, 6}, {2, 1, 6}}` for instance.

Comment: @Sjoerd Yes, that is my understanding.

Comment: Yea.  @SjoerdC.deVries   Agreed.

Answer (score 3):

just a tip in this context:
when using non-atomar objects like `Sqrt[...]` you might get unexpected results:

```
SortBy[Range[10], -Sqrt[#] &]
{9, 4, 1, 8, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10}
```

this is due to

> Sort usually orders expressions by putting shorter ones first, and
>   then comparing parts in a depth-first manner. (Mathematica reference manual).

Always use N, when a numeric sort is desired.

Comment: Good tip.  If "atomar" is not a typo does it mean something besides atomic?

Comment: @Mr. "a tomar" means "Let's drink!" in Spanish

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is relevant to the question.